# saving a text file using JFileChooser

Tags: jfilechooser

I am writing a small program where are user enters some information into text fields and then has the option to save that information using JFileChooser. I have not been able to figure out how to get it to save. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

```
   public class Program implements ActionListener{
        JMenuItem loadMenuItem, saveMenuItem, quitMenuItem;
        JFrame frame;
        JPanel mainPanel, inputPanel, listPanel;
        JLabel firstNameLabel, lastNameLabel, rentLabel, listLabel;
        JTextField firstNameTextField, lastNameTextField, rentTextField;
        JButton addButton;
        JList list;
        DefaultListModel<TenantInfo> listModel;
        JScrollPane scrollPane;
        public ArrayList<TenantInfo>tenantInfo;

    private void saveFile() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
            int userSelected = jfc.showSaveDialog(null);
            if(userSelected == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                try{
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(jfc.getSelectedFile());
                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

                    for(TenantInfo t : tenantInfo){
                        oos.writeObject(t);
                    }
                    oos.writeObject(tenantInfo.get(0));

                    oos.close();
                    fos.close();
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: I get a nullPointerException here: for(TenantInfo t : tenantInfo)

Comment: Well, is `tenantInfo` null? Are you initializing it before that method runs?